# Getting google search results with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I was looking for a way to retrieve Google search results, using RoR.
I could see that a while ago it used to be done only by scraping the HTML pages (Scruby, Nokogiri, Mecheanize...). I was wondering first, if it's legit, second, I didn't really undesrtand how can you rely on another site's HTML and CSS - what would happen if it's changed in the next day... Maybe I missed something there?
Then I saw that Google offers an API for doing it, but I couldn't find any Rails plugin that handles it.

Does anybody know any?

Thanks :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [googleajax gem](https://github.com/geemus/googleajax), but it can only return up to 100 results.

```
GoogleAjax::Search.web('ruby')[:results].each do |result|
  puts result.inspect
end
```

Other than that, yes you can scrape google results, no it's against their [ToS](http://www.google.com/accounts/TOS) (see 5.3), yes you still can do it a little and no one will notice or take action.

By the way, sites don't normally change HTML markup often, and Google probably does it less often than average. Screen scraping is stable enough to be practically useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply! Regarding the GoogleAjax, is that possible that the functions like GoogleAjax::Search.web isn't able to get parameters...? I can't define number of pages or results? I also noticed it returns only full HTML code (not cleaned, and needs parsing)?

Comment: @Moozly, I added a code example to my answer. I can confirm it works with googleajax 1.0.1. You can iterate search results by passing `:start => 10` as the second parameter to `web()`

Comment: @Leonid, so according to what you wrote and what I saw at Google's api, I can only get total of 100 results? What if I need more...? :-(

Comment: @Moozly, screen scraping it is then.

Comment: Google will notice and take action. They will start sending captchas.

Comment: @pguardiario, thanks. It's just a one time thing, so it will be o.k...
Yet, I still have some problems getting what I need :-(.
I'm using Nokogiri. I'm trying to extract more than just URLs and using the followings:
- doc.xpath("//ol/li[@class='g']") #for num=100, I sometimes somehow get 102 results (last one is News result - which shows up only part of the times, not sure by which rule).
Also, why on the above items:
item.css("div.vsc div.s") works, but item.css("div.vsc div.s span.st") doesn't?

Comment: For just the first 100 try: doc.xpath("//ol/li[@class='g']")[0..99]

Comment: Thanks, already did it, but not that nice...

Comment: Also, of course, having another problem :-(...
With Hebrew characters in the URL (which works ok on the browser, but not in Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) when url contains them